# Server Health Monitoring - Data model in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, nosql, cassandra-3.0, datamodel

I am designing the Architecture for Server Health Monitoring,

**I have the scenario : A Cluster has 'N' number of nodes, Each Cluster has 'N' number of nodes, Each nodes has 'N' number of resources like below 
Cluster -> (One to Many) -> Nodes (One to Many) -> Resources (like Memory, CPU which has attributes like name, type, unit, used, total etc.,)**

which is the best data modeling for this use case in Cassandra and Could you let me know why?

Also, I need to update and query,

1) Query Resources of all the nodes by nodeId
2) Total resources of CPU / Memory in a cluster?

```
CREATE TYPE resources (                                                                       
        id int PRIMARY KEY,
        name text,
        type text, 
        unit text,                                                            
        description text,
        used int,
        total int,
        PRIMARY KEY (id, type)                                                                 
    );

    CREATE TABLE nodes (                                                                       
        id int PRIMARY KEY,
        name text, 
        ip text,                                                           
        resources frozen <resources>                                                                  
    );

    CREATE TABLE cluster (
        id int PRIMARY KEY,
        node text
    );
```

My question is I am expecting the best practice for this use case.

Thanks,
Harry

Comment: What have you done so far ?

Comment: updated @AshrafulIslam